# Does mongodb have cursor?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm background of Microsoft SQL server and i'm beginner of Mongodb and Nodejs now. I've 2 collections.
My question is simple about Student Score Management.

*Collection A*: List_of_Students (_id, name)

*Collection B*: Scores_of_Student (_id, subject, type_of_score, value)

Collection A **reference** to B. How can i make a query to list students have score and students doesn't have score. After that, I can manipulate data and update, insert to score of student table.

In MSSQL, I use a temp table to list all students and using cursor to update student have a score in that table. Does mongoDB have this method or help me with another method.

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you store the data about `scores` into `student` collections only, because thats what you do in mongodb ? keeping related data into same collection while creating subdocument inside it

Comment: @Trigges: you might want to read the MongoDB documentation _thoroughly_ before continuing, namely the [MongoDB and SQL comparison](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) and the [introduction into Data Modeling for mongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/). Another good idea could be to take the free(as in beer) class [MongoDB for node.js developers](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about) by MongoDB university.